# Cross website tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I asked this on [Programmers meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/cross-website-tags) and got no answers, not even a comment.

It'd be really nice if we had a way to see if the tag exists on other sites or not from the wiki page of the tag.

For example, if I'm currently viewing the "Ruby" tag, I would like to know if this tag exists on SO or gamedev or any other site, with links to the other wiki pages, of course